# What can I call to check the API OAuth token is valid?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am using the PHP Google API client and wrapping it in a generic library for use over a number of projects. The library persists the access tokens and renewal tokens, so offline access is possible. The application using the library could be using *any* scopes it likes, giving access to any Google API services that is needs.

Now, I would like at some points in the library to be able to check that the stored OAuth access token is still valid, that it has not expired or been revoked. I understand that can only be done by calling up an API service.

So the question is: what service? Is there a Google API service that can be called up, and will be guaranteed to be available no matter what scopes the access token was granted for?

Comment: This seems to fetch details of the authorising user from Google: `$oauth2 = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($client); $oauth2->userinfo->get();` I've checked the HTTP requests and response, and there is certainly data moving over the API. I think I need the `user` and `email` scopes to access it, but those scopes aren't reaching into any part of the account that the authorising user should not need to agree to for the application. I'll write this up as an answer if I don't get a better one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna check that the stored OAuth access token is still valid or not, you can call method `isAccessTokenExpired()` from `Google_Client` object.

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
    $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshToken);
}
```

Comment: No, this function just looks at the local time and the creation time held in cache against the token. It does not in any way confirm the token is valid, unfortunately. [source](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/a7a6cc6d24a664f1658e5b8cbd408ba989340a78/src/Google/Client.php#L455)